# I Want to do fb post same as foursquare api with map do(for checked in into venue). Any idea?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, foursquare

I'm trying to achieve a facebook post as four square API does for check in into venue. Check in api deperecated and no luck with facebook open graph api. Can anyone help me in this regards?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't do it for iOS yet but I've used Facebook API for android and the new approach for check-in is sending a feed post with place parameter. I guess it should be the same.

Add message and place parameters and post. Here is how to post a feed to wall. [Fb docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/)

note: place parameter must be facebook id of the place.